Grid Template Layout - aligning multiple items in same column (self align start)
I'm trying to use grid template to build a layout for different views (mobile / desktop etc).
I'm using grid-template-area.
For mobile it is easy since I'm using just 1 column but when I go to desktop I want to build 2 columns.
For desktop first column should show as in the image, but for the second column I'd like to align everything on top, next to each other.
Is there a way to move description just after title without any space or it is not possible with grid?
Please note that the height of any box should remain dynamic.
Current Behavior

Expected Behavior



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
  min-height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.price {
  grid-area: price;
  background-color: teal;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.config {
  grid-area: config;
  background-color: purple;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.add {
  grid-area: add;
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.carousel {
  grid-area: carousel;
  background-color: orange;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.features {
  grid-area: features;
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.specifications {
  grid-area: specifications;
  background-color: gray;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.related {
  grid-area: related;
  background-color: aqua;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "title" 
                       "description"
                       "price"
                       "config"
                       "add"
                       "carousel"
                       "features"
                       "specifications"
                       "related";
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "carousel title"
                         "features description" 
                         "specifications price" 
                         "related config" 
                         ". add";
  }
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 42px;
  padding: 12px;
  align-self: start;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
      <div class="description">DESCRIPTION</div>
      <div class="price">PRICE</div>
      <div class="config">CONFIG</div>
      <div class="add">ADD TO BASKET</div>
      <div class="carousel">CAROUSEL</div>
      <div class="features">KEY FEATURES</div>
      <div class="specifications">SPECIFICATIONS</div>
      <div class="related">RELATED PRODUCTS</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




If you want to change the order of the blocks in the mobile version, for example put .carousel after .title, I offer you a slightly improved version @SyndRain.
Namely, apply display: contents; to .sidebar in the mobile version - this will allow you to move the blocks as you like using grid-template-areas:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
  min-height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.price {
  grid-area: price;
  background-color: teal;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.config {
  grid-area: config;
  background-color: purple;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.add {
  grid-area: add;
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.carousel {
  grid-area: carousel;
  background-color: orange;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.features {
  grid-area: features;
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.specifications {
  grid-area: specifications;
  background-color: gray;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.related {
  grid-area: related;
  background-color: aqua;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "title" 
                       "carousel"
                       "description"
                       "price"
                       "config"
                       "add"
                       "features"
                       "specifications"
                       "related";
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "carousel sidebar"
                         "features sidebar"
                         "specifications sidebar"
                         "related sidebar"
                         "add sidebar";
  }
}

.sidebar {
  display: contents;
  @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      display: block;
      grid-area: sidebar;
  }
}

.wrapper div:not(.sidebar) {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px;
  align-self: start;
  font-size: 32px;
  @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="carousel">CAROUSEL</div>
  <div class="features">KEY FEATURES</div>
  <div class="specifications">SPECIFICATIONS</div>
  <div class="related">RELATED PRODUCTS</div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    <div class="description">DESCRIPTION</div>
    <div class="price">PRICE</div>
    <div class="config">CONFIG</div>
    <div class="add">ADD TO BASKET</div>
  </div>
</div>




This works for me, tested on safari, edge, firefox and chrome. Thanks for your explanation. I can reorder as I want in different screen sizes.

Simply wrap the divs that are going to the side into a wrapper and they will by default stick together without gaps.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
  min-height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.price {
  grid-area: price;
  background-color: teal;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.config {
  grid-area: config;
  background-color: purple;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.add {
  grid-area: add;
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.carousel {
  grid-area: carousel;
  background-color: orange;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.features {
  grid-area: features;
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.specifications {
  grid-area: specifications;
  background-color: gray;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.related {
  grid-area: related;
  background-color: aqua;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "sidearea" "carousel" "features" "specifications" "related" "add";
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "carousel sidearea" "features sidearea" "specifications sidearea" "related sidearea" "add sidearea";
  }
}

.side-area {
  grid-area: sidearea;
}

.wrapper>div:not(.side-area),
.side-area>div {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 42px;
  padding: 12px;
  align-self: start;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="carousel">CAROUSEL</div>
  <div class="features">KEY FEATURES</div>
  <div class="specifications">SPECIFICATIONS</div>
  <div class="related">RELATED PRODUCTS</div>
  <div class="side-area">
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    <div class="description">DESCRIPTION</div>
    <div class="price">PRICE</div>
    <div class="config">CONFIG</div>
    <div class="add">ADD TO BASKET</div>
  </div>
</div>




This changes the order in the mobile version. For example, if you want to put CAROUSEL after TITLE

@imghvost what do you mean? The mobile version follows exactly OP's template-area order. "title"
"description"
"price"
"config"
"add"
"carousel"
"features"
"specifications"
"related".

It is, but it's not a very universal answer

Well this is the easiest solution for OP especially the two columns aren’t the same width so multi-column layout won’t work. Maybe in the future Mansory layout will be able to achieve this, but it’s not even close to widely support. I doubt there’s a more universal solution but I’ll be happy to learn if you do have one ;)

Thank you both imghvost and SyndRain for your time and solution. Indeed the order can be any in both mobile and desktop or tablet and so on. I didn't know we can wrap in a div and use display content to keep the template-areas and reorder as we want. Makes so much sense now, I can even add display flex column and reorder for sidebar child elements.
